# What am I doing wrong? Ajax Calender ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ajax, calendar

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox1_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
        ClearTime="True" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
    </asp:CalendarExtender>
```

The above code does not popup the calender when I type in a value in textbox. I worked with Ajax a while ago and it used to work fine. What am I missing?

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and Ajax library 3.5. Other Ajax Controls like Edit works fine.

Oh I spent two+ hours on this which is something very easy.

Comment: I think you might need an update panel...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my problem was the script manager line

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

Change this to

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="Server" EnableScriptGlobalization="true"
        EnableScriptLocalization="true" ID="ScriptManager1" ScriptMode="Debug" CombineScripts="false" />
```

and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use cc1 for CalenderExtender as follows.

```
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox1_CalendarExtender" runat="server" ClearTime="True" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
</cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

Comment: posted my own answer above, please check my answer.